# scrartcl letter creates unwanted "-" signs (foldmarks) in between sections

Tags: letters, scrartcl, scrletter

I am writing a cover letter with the scrartcl documentclass, using the scrletter package. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref,todonotes,longtable}
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.75}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone, breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, anchorcolor= webbrown, citecolor= webblue, filecolor= webbrown, linkcolor= webblue, menucolor= webbrown, urlcolor= webbrown, citebordercolor= 1 0 0, menubordercolor=1 0 0, urlbordercolor=1 0 0, runbordercolor=1 0 0}

\begin{document}
\date{}
%\setkomavar{fromname}{Name of Sender}
%\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address of Sender}
\begin{letter}{December 14, 2021\\To:\\X\\Y\\Role X,Y\\Company}
  \opening{Dear X, Dear Y,}

   The first  citation


  \closing{Yours sincerely,}

 \bibliographystyle{rfs}
 \bibliography{references}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I am using scrartcl because I want to integrate the bibliography contained in the file "references" in the tex. Everything works but the compiled document contains some "-" lines in between sections, and I really do not want them. How do I remove them? I tried also in Overleaf instead of TexWorks, but same result.

[image]

Comment: That are foldermarks ...

Comment: sorry my English :) how do I get rid of those?

Comment: `[foldmarks=false]{scrletter}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the option `foldmarks=false` to get rid off all foldmarks for the letter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[foldmarks=false]{scrletter} % <=============================
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref,todonotes,longtable}
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.75}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone, breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, anchorcolor= webbrown, citecolor= webblue, filecolor= webbrown, linkcolor= webblue, menucolor= webbrown, urlcolor= webbrown, citebordercolor= 1 0 0, menubordercolor=1 0 0, urlbordercolor=1 0 0, runbordercolor=1 0 0}

\begin{document}
\date{}
%\setkomavar{fromname}{Name of Sender}
%\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address of Sender}
\begin{letter}{December 14, 2021\\To:\\X\\Y\\Role X,Y\\Company}
  \opening{Dear X, Dear Y,}

   The first  citation


  \closing{Yours sincerely,}

 \bibliographystyle{rfs}
 \bibliography{references}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]